# Comparing two texts php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to find which are in each array and how they differ, but it says all are not in the array with the in_array function.

I need to find which are to be removed and which will need to be added, return each as an array to jquery.

```
// prepares array
function prep($string){
    $separator = "/n";
    $string = explode($separator , $string );
    $string = array_map('trim', $string);
    return $string;
}

// lines to test
$lines = 'guest13 /n guest14 /n guest16 /n';
$lines2 = 'guest13 /n guest16 /n guest17 /n';

// declares storage for later
$add = array();
$rem = array();

// tests lines to see if the same
similar_text($lines, $lines2, $percent);

// declares arrays 
$linestest = array();
$linestest2 = array();

// filters lines to be tested
$linestest = prep($lines);
$lines2test = prep($lines2);

if ($percent != 100) {

    // checks if it needs to be removed
    foreach ($linestest as $line => $mow) {

        if (!in_array('$mow', $linestest2, true)) {
            $rem[] = $mow;
            echo '<br />remove ' . $mow;
        }
    }
    foreach ($lines2test as $sigh => $wow) {

        if (!in_array('$wow', $linestest, true)) {
            $add[] = $wow;
            echo '<br />add ' . $wow;
        }
        // echos each out
    }
    foreach ($rem as $new) {
        $mows .= 'remove this ' . $new;
    }
    foreach ($add as $new) {
        $mows .= 'add this ' . $new;
    }
    echo '<br />end of string ' . $mows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have several mistakes. I've removed your comments and added my own so you can better understand what I changed:

```
function prep($string) {
    $separator = "/n";
    // added the following line to prevent empty value in array
    $string = trim($string, $separator);
    $string = explode($separator, $string);
    $string = array_map('trim', $string);
    return $string;
}

$lines = 'guest13 /n guest14 /n guest16 /n'; 
$lines2 = 'guest13 /n guest16 /n guest17 /n';

$add = array();
$rem = array();

similar_text($lines, $lines2, $percent);

$linestest = array();
$linestest2 = array();

$linestest = prep($lines);
$lines2test = prep($lines2);

if ($percent != 100) {
    $mows = ''; // added this line to initialize variable and prevent undefined notice
    foreach ($linestest as $mow) { // removed key declaration, you're not using it
        // changed the following from !in_array to in_array
        // using $lines2test instead of $linestest2
        if (in_array($mow, $lines2test, true)) {
            $rem[] = $mow;
            echo '<br />remove ' . $mow ;
        }
    }
    foreach ($lines2test as $wow) { // removed key declaration, you're not using it
        // using $wow instead of $cow
        if (!in_array($wow, $linestest, true)) {
            $add[] = $wow;
            echo '<br />add ' . $wow;
        }
    } 
    foreach ($rem as $new) {
        $mows .= 'remove this ' . $new;
    }
    foreach ($add as $new) {
        $mows .= 'add this ' . $new;
    }
    echo '<br />end of string ' . $mows;
}
```

**Output:**

```
remove guest13
remove guest16
add guest17
end of string remove this guest13remove this guest16add this guest17
```

If you want a shorter way to do it without the loops, here is a condensed version:

```
function prep($string, $separator = '/n') {
    return array_map('trim', explode($separator, trim($string, $separator)));
}

$lines = 'guest13 /n guest14 /n guest16 /n'; 
$lines2 = 'guest13 /n guest16 /n guest17 /n';

$arr1 = prep($lines);
$arr2 = prep($lines2);

// all values from $arr1 present in $arr2
// outputs: guest13 and guest16
$remove = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);

// all values from $arr2 NOT present in $arr1
// outputs: guest17
$add = array_diff($arr2, $arr1);

// alternative to above, if you want both guest14 and guest17
$add = array_diff($arr1, $arr2) + array_diff($arr2, $arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've pretty much stuck it all into one function as well tweak some parts to make it clearer. All you need to do is pass the string format given as the two parameters. The return is the array of the guests to ADD and REMOVE in 2D array. I've not added the `if($percent != 100)` but I'm sure you can pass that variable as a parameter and inject that line where needed within the function.

The code is heavily commented so hopefully it will be clear.

```
// lines to test
$lines = 'guest13 /n guest14 /n guest16 /n'; 
$lines2 = 'guest13 /n guest16 /n guest17 /n';

$addArray = checkData($lines, $lines2); //Call check() function 

var_dump($addArray); //Check return of array is correct

function checkData($inputOne, $inputTwo) { //Two strings as paramters in the format given

    $arrayOne = explode('/n', str_replace(' ', '', $inputOne)); //Replace whitespace with blank
    $arrayTwo = explode('/n', str_replace(' ', '', $inputTwo)); //Replace whitespace with blank

    foreach($arrayOne as $value) { //First Compare ArrayOne

        if(in_array($value, $arrayTwo)) { //Check to see if iteration of loop value is in ArrayTwo

            $rem[] = $value;  
            echo '<br />remove ' . $value;

        } elseif (!in_array($value, $arrayTwo)) { //Add to array if not in Array Two

            $add[] = $value;
            echo '<br /> add ' . $value;
        }      
    }

    foreach($arrayTwo as $value) {

        if(!in_array($value, $arrayOne)) { //Check to see if iteration of loop value is NOT in ArrayOne

            $add[] = $value;
            echo '<br /> add ' . $value; 

        } elseif (!in_array($value, $rem)) { //Compare against Array Rem to make sure we dont add duplicates

            $rem[] = $value;  
            echo '<br />remove ' . $value; 
        }
    }

    $outArray = ['Add' => $add, 'Remove' => $rem]; //2D Array 

    return $outArray; //Return Array
}
```

**Output**

```
remove guest13
add guest14
remove guest16
add guest17

array(2) { ["Add"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "guest14" [1]=> string(7) "guest17" } ["Remove"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "guest13" [1]=> string(7) "guest16"} }
```

**Edit!**

*Misread question and edited so it now returns both arrays in 2D array.*